# How to plot plotly gauge charts next to each other with python?

Tags: python, plotly, gauge

I have two gauge plots in my script and want to visualize them, side by side.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig1 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",    value=400,    domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},    title={'text': "Speed 1"}))

fig2 = go.Figure(go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",    value=250,    domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},    title={'text': "Speed 2"}))
```

How can show `fig1` and `fig2` side by side?

Comment: You've received two similar but each in their own way valuable and working suggestions. If you found them useful yourself, please consider awarding upvotes. And perhaps also consider marking the one that best suits your needs as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track using the `domain` attribute, but your exact specifications are off. With the rest of the setup in the complete code below, the following specifications produces the associated plot:

#### Domain specs

```
 domain={'x': [0.0, 0.4], 'y': [0.0, 1]}

 domain={'x': [0.6, 1.0], 'y': [0., 1.00]}
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px

# traces with separate domains to form a subplot
trace1 = go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",    value=400,    domain={'x': [0.0, 0.4], 'y': [0.0, 1]},    title={'text': "Speed 1"})

trace2 = go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",    value=250,    domain={'x': [0.6, 1.0], 'y': [0., 1.00]},    title={'text': "Speed 2"})

# layout and figure production
layout = go.Layout(height = 600,
                   width = 600,
                   autosize = False,
                   title = 'Side by side gauge diagrams')
fig = go.Figure(data = [trace1, trace2], layout = layout)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Really appreciate this - thanks.  Is it possible to do a side-by-side gauge diagrams where, instead of trace1 and trace2 being the full go.Indicator() code, you instead call trace1 and trace2 from a function that creates a gauge indicator chart and returns fig.show() for each gauge indicator created using the function?  In other words, can I call a function that uses go.Indicator() to create a gauge chart instead of creating the gauge chart at trace1 and trace2 as you did above?  I tried it but can't get it to work.  Maybe the function is returning the wrong thing (fig.show())?  Thanks!

Comment: @GbG Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure if what you're asking is in fact possible. If it is, I'm sure you'll get the assistance you're seeking if you find the time to write it up as a new question. I for one will make sure to take a closer look at it if you do.

Comment: Thanks @vestland.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can show both figures side by side using subplots.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

trace1 = go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",    value=400,    domain={'row' : 1, 'column' : 1}, title={'text': "Speed 1"})
trace2 = go.Indicator(mode="gauge+number",    value=250,    domain={'row' : 1, 'column' : 2}, title={'text': "Speed 2"})

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1,
    cols=2,
    specs=[[{'type' : 'indicator'}, {'type' : 'indicator'}]],
    )

fig.append_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)
fig.append_trace(trace2, row=1, col=2)

fig.show()
```

[image]